# Parsing terminal symbols with partial match

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, grammar

I have a grammar which is something like:

```
S -> 'My' 'age' 'is' NUM
NUM -> '18', '20'
```

the parser I build with such grammar can parse sentences like `My age is 18` but if my actual sentences is something like `My age is 20>` -- where `20>` meaning more than 20 -- it fails.

So I am asking: is there any way to force the parser to accept partial matches on terminal symbols?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am quite a noob with `ntlk` so maybe I am approaching the problem in the worst way possible. Any hint would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nltk's CFG is a teaching tool, not a serious NLP framework. It does not provide support for any kind of open-vocabulary items (which will inevitably result in unknown words, including unknown numbers). Your best option is to pre-process your input, e.g. replace all numerals with a fixed number (or a symbol like `#NUM#`) that is recognized by your grammar. Then if you need the original numerals, you can post-process the parser results and put them back in.